# Bad substitution in shell script in line:8

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

```bash
#!/bin/bash
exclude_interfaces="enp0s31f6 lo wlp2s0" 
 
while true; do
  interfaces=$(ls /sys/class/net)
    
  for interface in $interfaces; do
    if [[ ! " ${exclude_interfaces[$*]} " =~ $interface ]]; then ##error in this line(bad substitution)

      if [[ $(cat /sys/class/net/$interface/carrier) -eq 1 ]]; then
        new_name="eth044"

        sudo ip link set dev " $interface " down
        sudo ip link set dev " $interface " name "$new_name"
        sudo ip link set dev "$new_name" up

        echo Interface name "$interface" changed successfully to "$new_name".

      fi
    fi
  done
    
  sleep 1
done
```

its showing:

> "script.sh: 8: Bad substitution" in line 8

In this problem, I'm creating a shell script to detect any interface is connected to the computer and change and name of that particular interface.

I have to run this script automatically once the interface is connected. This script is running if I manually run the script.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). `sleep 1 done` simply does not make sense. Also, point out in your code the line where the error occurs.

Comment: @user1934428 have pointed out in code where the error occurs.

Comment: Yes, but do you want us to **count** the lines for you, to see which one is number 8? Even more, befoe you edited the issue, so that the code is now visible properly, we couldn't even see all the line breaks. The way you are doing now - indicating the error place in a comment - is good.

Comment: May I suggest that you put a `echo $BASH_VERSION` before entering the loop, and tell us what version you see?

Comment: @user1934428 its showing as "5.0.17(1)-release".

Comment: The second line (exclude_interfaces...) is wrong, it does not do what you think.

Comment: Just do exclude_interfaces="enp0s31f6 lo wlp2s0", then put spaces around $interface and check well the test.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica have edited the code and tested but still its showing as bad substitution as above.Have edited the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following test script, it should let you start:

```
#!/bin/bash
exclude_interfaces=" enp0s31f6 lo wlp2s0 "

interfaces=$(ls /sys/class/net)
echo "interfaces found: $interfaces"

for interface in $interfaces; do
  if [[ ! "$exclude_interfaces" =~ " $interface " ]]; then
    echo "Doing $interface"
  fi
done
```

It uses simple regexp like you, but with normal strings.
echo commands are inserted to debug, instead of doing anything.

See the other answer by user1934428 which explains were the errors were.

Comment: script.sh: 8: [[: not found its showing an error like this in the following line
if [[ ! "$exclude_interfaces" =~ " $interface " ]]; then

Comment: This is strange because 1. I tested this script and, 2. the "[[" syntax was already present in your script and it didn't generate errors. Are you sure there is an "if" before the "[["?

Comment: yeah "if" is present before the"[["

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your script:

Your variable `exclude_interfaces` is  a string holding the text `[enp0s31f6lowlp2s0]` (as you can see if you do a `echo $exclude_interfaces`. I see that you have edited the posting in the meantime, and now the variable contains the string `enp0s31f6 lo wlp2s0`

You address this string as if it were an array, by doing a `${exclude_interfaces[...]}`.

Furthermore, you use as "array index" the special variable `$*`, which means "list of all parameters to your script". This does not make sense and is the cause of your error message. You can verfiy this type of error by running the script with `set -x` turned on.

Another, possibly minor, point, which is unrelated to your error: If `/sys/class/net` contains an entry which has a space in it, this will break your script, because word-splitting occurs in `for interface in $interfaces`.

**UPDATE**

Yet another problem occurs, if one of the entries in /sys/class/net contains a special regex character (for instance a period).

To fix these problems:

I would first loop over the entries in /sys/class/net:

```
cd /sys/class/net
for interface in *
do 
   ...
```

Then I would not use regexp-matching, but globbing

```
# Use comma as markers to ease pattern matching
exclude_interfaces=",enp0s31f6,lo,wlp2s0,"
```

...

```
if [[ ! $exclude_interfaces == *,$interface,* ]]
then
  ....
```